# Generate Dynamic AJAX Toolkit controls using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, asynchronous

I want to create a (Dynamic) AJAX control `(AsyncFileUpload)` using JavaScript or jQuery, Is it possible to create?

Comment: what is the reason of not having it as server control and just hide/show it when needed ?

Comment: i planned to generate All the controls dynamically by the XML Structure.i done other html controls dynamically but this only i want to do.Every Controls May be Repeat as per structure.Please give me the solution

Comment: do you have this xml on the server ?

Comment: i have a generic Handler for jquery plugin (ajaxfileupload) i want to pass some arguments from page(jquery/javascript) (Ex. Dynamic Save Path , autogenerated filename,etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the [ajaxFileUpload](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/) jQuery plugin?

Comment: I Got the Error TypeError: $.ajaxFileUpload is not a function

Comment: You need to include ajaxFileUpload.js, you can download the plugin from here : http://www.phpletter.com/DOWNLOAD/

Comment: How can i pass arguments to generic Handler (AjaxFileuploader.ashx) from jquery or javascript

Answer (score -1):

Basically something like this should work, check control ids to reference corresponding controls you'll have

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Sys.Extended.UI.AjaxFileUpload, 
        { "allowedFileTypes":"jpg,png,gif",
          "clientStateField":$get("ctrlClientStateField"),
          "contextKey":"contextKey",
          "maximumNumberOfFiles":4,
          "postBackUrl":"/submitreport.aspx",
          "throbber":$get("ctrlThrobber")
        }, null, null, $get("ctrlControl"));
});
```

Here is source code of client side code for control, which you can make use of in order to figure out parameters - http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/7ab51a2e2ccf#Server%2fAjaxControlToolkit%2fAsyncFileUpload%2fAsyncFileUpload.pre.js

Comment: i have a generic Handler for jquery plugin (ajaxfileupload) i want to pass some arguments from page(jquery/javascript) (Ex. Dynamic Save Path , autogenerated filename,etc...)

Comment: "We encountered a problem loading "Server%2fAjaxControlToolkit%2fAsyncFileUpload%2fAsyncFileUpload.pre.js". If you continuously encounter this issue, please contact us." (This is why Stackoverflow answers should not depend on the content of external links).

Comment: Operative word: "was".

Comment: @Quentin first of all, you can at least be polite asking for help. Second it is really easy to find sources even if link is broken

Comment: @Quentin http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/7ab51a2e2ccf#Server/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.pre.js